# How to get User Image from Microsoft Graph SDK

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to get the binary value of Image from Microsoft Graph SDK, here is my code and response

```
var userRequest = graphClient.Users[{id}].Photo
            .Request();

        var user = await userRequest.GetAsync();
```

response:

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users('userId')/photo/$entity",
"@odata.mediaContentType": "image/Jpeg",
"width": 503,
"height": 626,
"id": "503X626"
}
```

any suggestion how to get the value of the image in specific size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after long search I find the way

```
            //get the photo
            var requestUserPhoto = graphClient.Users[{id}].Photo.Request();
            var resultsUserPhoto = requestUserPhoto.GetAsync().Result;

            //create the file
            var profilePhotoNamePath = "Images/" + {id}+ ".jpeg";
            
            // get user photo content
            var requestUserPhotoFile = 
                 graphClient.Users[{id}].Photos["64x64"].Content.Request();
            var resultsUserPhotoFile = requestUserPhotoFile.GetAsync().Result;

            // create the image
            var profilePhoto = System.IO.File.Create(profilePhotoNamePath);

            resultsUserPhotoFile.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
            resultsUserPhotoFile.CopyTo(profilePhoto);
```

Comment: This seems to be a bit out of date, but I realize from this example that I could do something like `await graphClient.Users["{objectId}"].Photo.Content.GetAsync()` and get a stream from which to return. Thanks!